# Xcode Swift, Как сделать вход микрофона из гарнитуры, а выход из динамика телефона?

Tags: xcode, swift, ios11

Как сделать вход микрофона из гарнитуры, а выход из динамика телефона?

Вот код, который я использую, но он записывает вход из телефона, а не из гарнитуры.

```
let audioEngine  = AVAudioEngine()
var audioFilePlayer: AVAudioPlayerNode = AVAudioPlayerNode()

var buffer: AVAudioPCMBuffer!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    try! audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playAndRecord, mode: AVAudioSession.Mode.default, options: [])
    try! audioSession.setActive(true)
    try! audioSession.overrideOutputAudioPort(AVAudioSession.PortOverride.speaker)

    let inputNode = audioEngine.inputNode
    inputNode.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 2000, format: inputNode.inputFormat(forBus: 0)) {
        (buffer: AVAudioPCMBuffer!, time: AVAudioTime!) -> Void in
        self.audioFilePlayer.scheduleBuffer(buffer, at: nil, options: [], completionHandler: nil)
    }

    audioEngine.attach(audioFilePlayer)
    audioEngine.connect(audioFilePlayer, to: audioEngine.mainMixerNode, format: inputNode.inputFormat(forBus: 0))
    audioEngine.prepare()
    try! audioEngine.start()

    audioFilePlayer.play()

}
```

Кто-нибудь знает как использовать вход из гарнитуры в моем случае, но чтоб воспроизводился в громком динамике устройства?

Или может у кого-то есть свой вариант решения задачи? Спасибо.

Comment: По поводу выхода с телефона - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession/1616582-setoutputdatasource, а по поводу гарнитуры вроде как - https://stackoverflow.com/a/52460651/8996758

Comment: Не получается, система переключается либо на телефон, либо на гарнитуру, а динамик телефона и микрофон гарнитуры задействовать не выходит.